# Confusion in the syntax of setOnEditorActionListener method

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-edittext

I came across the following program while learning android in one of the websites:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
// add the custom view to the action bar
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_view);
EditText search = (EditText) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.searchfield);
search.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

  @Override
  public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
      KeyEvent event) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Search triggered",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return false;
  }
});
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
    | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
}

}
```

Here a listener is attached to the custom view of EditText which is basically a search item. Could someone please explain the syntax in the:

```
  setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

  @Override
  public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
      KeyEvent event) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Search triggered",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return false;
  }
})
```

As far as I can understand there is a definition of the function inside the parameter of the function "setOnEditorActionListener". Can someone please help me with the understanding as correct or incorrect?

Comment: Learn Java. Google it.

Comment: Hint: This is interface implementation. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use addTextChangedListener instead setOnEditorActionListener.

```
 search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: How come this is an answer to the question?